# What is the problem with hue in my swarmplot?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, swarmplot

I have this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/abcsds/pokemon/download. I loaded it and did some changes:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

pokemons=pd.read_csv('../input/pokemon/Pokemon.csv')

del pokemons['Type 2']
pokemons.rename(columns={'Type 1':'Type'},inplace=True)
```

What I want is to make some swarmplots for each stat of the each pokemons type with hue=Legendary. I want to visualize how are legendary pokemons situated. I already did  swarmplots without hue. Firstly, I needed to melt the dataframe:

```
pok_melt=pd.melt(pokemons,id_vars=['Name','Type','Legendary'],value_vars=['HP','Defense','Attack','Sp. Atk','Sp. Def','Speed'])
pok_melt.head()
```

Then, the code for swarmplots (At one point I needed the types names alphabetically ordered for another plot so that's why they are ordered):

```
list_types=pokemons['Type'].unique().tolist() 
list_types.sort()
list_types

plt.figure(figsize=(17,22))
k=1
for i in list_types:
    plt.subplot(6,3,k)
    k=k+1
    sns.swarmplot(x=pok_melt.variable,y=pok_melt[pok_melt.Type==i].value,palette='gist_stern')
    plt.title(i)
    plt.xlabel('')
```

These are some of the swarmplots:

[image]

So I tried to do this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(17,22))
k=1
for i in list_types:
    plt.subplot(6,3,k)
    k=k+1
    sns.swarmplot(x=pok_melt.variable,y=pok_melt[pok_melt.Type==i].value,palette='gist_stern',
    hue=pok_melt.Legendary)
    plt.title(i)
    plt.xlabel('')
```

And i get this error: *IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 69 but corresponding boolean dimension is 800*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter column `Legendary` like `y` parameter:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(17,22))
k=1
for i in list_types:
    plt.subplot(6,3,k)
    k=k+1
    sns.swarmplot(x=pok_melt.variable,
                  y=pok_melt[pok_melt.Type==i].value,
                  hue=pok_melt[pok_melt.Type==i].Legendary,
                  palette='gist_stern')
    plt.title(i)
    plt.xlabel('')
```

Or better is filter only once fo variable `df` and assign columns `df['value']` to `y` and `df['Legendary']` to `hue`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(17,22))
k=1
for i in list_types:
    plt.subplot(6,3,k)
    k=k+1
    df = pok_melt.loc[pok_melt.Type==i]

    sns.swarmplot(x=pok_melt.variable,
                  y=df['value'],
                  hue=df['Legendary'],
                  palette='gist_stern')
    plt.title(i)
    plt.xlabel('')
```